# Calling a Class Constructor in LINQ

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have been playing around with a few techniques but still not found something i'm happy with.

If I do something like;

```
        IQueryable<TestClass> tests = new MyDbContext()
            .LdbRecords
            .Select(r => new TestClass() { Id = r.RecordId, Name = r.RecordName });
        Console.WriteLine(tests.Count());
```

EF executes a relatively sensible query;

```
SELECT 
    [GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1]
FROM ( SELECT 
    COUNT(1) AS [A1]
    FROM [dbo].[ldb_record] AS [Extent1]
)  AS [GroupBy1]
```

I am trying to move away from using parameter-less constructors. The primary goal being- when we add a new property, we don't have to look too hard to update every instance where the class is newed up. Instead, we modify the constructor, this will then break any pieces of code newing up the class until the additional parameter is added (ensuring we don't forget to add the new property mapping anywhere). If there's a better way to do this, i'm all ears!

The constructor looks like;

```
        public TestClass(int id, string name)
        {
            Id = id;
            Name = name;
        }
```

Every technique I have found so far- for example;

```
        IEnumerable<TestClass> tests = new MyDbContext()
            .LdbRecords
            .AsEnumerable()
            .Select(r => new TestClass(r.RecordId, r.RecordName));
        Console.WriteLine(tests.Count());
```

Is having a detrimental impact on the SQL query generation;

```
SELECT 
  [Extent1].[record_id] AS [record_id], 
  [Extent1].[record_name] AS [record_name], 
  [Extent1].[record_note] AS [record_note]
FROM [dbo].[ldb_record] AS [Extent1]
```

Is there a technique I can use (possibly using delegates or expressions or functions perhaps?) that will allow me to use my `TestClass` constructor without enumerating?

I would be happy having a private parameterless constructor in TestClass which a function/delegate etc could call?

Thanks

Comment: LINQ can only produce efficient queries if it understands what's going on. Injecting arbitrary code in the form of an external constructor call defeats this ability and forces intermediate materialization of the results, because the constructor could be doing "anything" and the expression compiler can't open up the method to peek inside. While workarounds to that are possible (by injecting your own query analysis) I suggest you don't work against the framework and use anonymous types, that are then instantiated as "real" types in LINQ to Objects. In other words, combine the queries you have.

Comment: Additionally, `Select col1, col2, col3 from table` is not a bad performing query. Whatever is happening like @JeroenMostert mentioned is likely in the funky enumeration  / instance creation of the concrete class.

Comment: I'm a little confused by your expectations. In the first example, All you ask Linq for in the end is a count, which it happily gives you. Do you not need the actual class instances from the first example? Once you actually ask for them, Linq will produce a query much closer to your second example.

Comment: EF Core supports Entities with Constructors, if that's what you want: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/constructors

Comment: @DStanley sorry, it's hard giving the right level of detail sometimes. This is a test piece of code which attempts to demonstrate my point. Imagine that a method would return `IQueryable<TestClass>` but there may be 10 methods which consume it... some simply `.Count()` but others might need to enumerate. Hope that helps?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft that's interesting! I will play with EF Core at some point, but for now we are stuck on .net framework. The fact that it's possible with core suggests it's not complete absurd what i'm trying to achieve :)

Comment: @LeeTickett An `IQueryable` is just the query, not the results. So if you use the query 10 times, you're going to get 10 different database calls. See my answer for hopefully a good explanation of why the queries are different.

Comment: Why do you have `AsEnumerable` in the second query?

Comment: @NetMage as it throws an exception without it.

Comment: @NetMage because Linq-to-Entities does not know how to translate the constructor to SQL. You have to use `AsEnumerable` to change the context from a database query to an in-memory query.

Comment: @DStanley Is this an EF 6.x limitation, because I though EF Core would handle it without issue, especially since it is the last `Select`.

Comment: @NetMage I haven't used Core, so it's possible. The point, however, is that the OP isn't actually enumerating the results, only asking for a count. Once the actual results are needed, the queries will be very similar (if not identical).

Comment: @DStanley No, I think the point is that a generic query with a parameterless constructor can later be used either for a count or to get results, but one with a parameterized constructor cannot because EF can't handle/won't ignore the constructor. This is one (of the few) place(s) where EF Core seems to work better than EF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with;

```
    IQueryable<TestClass> tests = new MyDbContext()
        .LdbRecords
        .Select(TestClass.ConvertPoco);
    Console.WriteLine(tests.Count());

    public class TestClass
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        private TestClass()
        {

        }

        public TestClass(int id, string name)
        {
            Id = id;
            Name = name;
        }

        public static Expression<Func<LdbRecord, TestClass>> ConvertPoco
        {
            get
            {
                return p => new TestClass() { Id = p.RecordId, Name = p.RecordName };
            }
        }
    }
```

Which evaluates to exactly the same query as the parameter-less constructor technique;

```
SELECT 
    [GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1]
FROM ( SELECT 
    COUNT(1) AS [A1]
    FROM [dbo].[ldb_record] AS [Extent1]
)  AS [GroupBy1]
```

Any advances on this?

Comment: I assume `ConvertPoco` is a method on `TestClass` and the default constructor has been made `private`, which at least achieves the goal of moving away from it from external code. You might want to clarify that.

Comment: @JeroenMostert spot on. I have added the full class definition as without it, you're quite right, it doesn't make complete sense. Thank you.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I have now managed to get the query to match exactly! I stupidly still had `tests` declared as `IEnumerable` from an earlier experiment... once I changed it back to `IQueryable` it now behaves exactly the same as using the parameter-less constructor and hence is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @LeeTickett I would bet if you replaced `.Select(TestClass.ConvertPoco)` with `.Select(p => new TestClass() { Id = p.RecordId, Name = p.RecordName })` you will get the same result. IOTW, you are just hiding the fact that you have a parameterless constructor while complicated the resulting code/query.

Comment: I'm not sure how I would feel about this. I mean I'm glad this works for you, but it seems like a weird solution to something solved with anonymous types or automapper. Additionally, your concrete class isn't a partial class, so it isn't from EF, which to me makes the code smell stronger...

Comment: I'm all ears @AustinTFrench if you have some suggestions? We don't use automapper. I have edited the original question in an attempt to articulate why we are moving away from parameter-less constructors.

Answer (score 0):

Your resulting SQL is different because the results they return are different. In the first example, all you ask the DB for (in the end) is a count, which Linq gives you. You never use the entities themselves, so Linq never queries for them.

In the second example, you ask for the entities via the `AsEnumerable` call, instructing Linq to switch from a database context to an in-memory context. So when you ask for a count, Linq has to fetch the records from the database *before* counting them.

If you actually *used* the entities in the first example, the DB query would be quite similar (maybe excluding the unused column, which should be negligible). If all you need is a count, then you don't need to use *any* constructor.

An easy test to see what query is generated if you enumerate the first example, change your output to :

```
Console.WriteLine(tests.AsEnumerable().Count());
```

Comment: I was only calling `AsEnumerable` as I was forced. I didn't want to but couldn't call the parameter based constructor otherwise. I have now found a solution (posted below). Thanks

Comment: OK, but I think you are missing the point. If all you want is a count, that's fine, but as soon as you start needing the actual items it's going to re-query the database with a very similar query to the one you don't want.

Comment: @LeeTickett In other words, your solution _does not give you all of the items_. It only gives you a count because that's all you ask for in the end (the provider sees that you want a count and ignores the expression that calls the class constructor).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what you are trying to solve is really already solved.

assuming:

```
 var tests = new MyDbContext()
        .LdbRecords         
        .Select(r => new LdbRecord());
```

You would get back an IQueryable of LdbRecord, and by calling .ToList() a list of those Database models, with all of it's properties.

What you should then be doing is using something like AutoMapper. Your next bit of logic would be something like:

```
 var results = Mapper.Map<TestClass>(tests.ToList());
```

You can configure your AutoMapper to match on property names, but also configure properties to be ignored, or matched 1 to 1.

```
var mapper = config.CreateMapper<LdbRecord, TestClass>();
mapper.ForMember(dest => dest.TestId, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Id));
```

This ensures that your code is written once (You don't have to go around the code base changing your parameters to the constructor.

Additionally, you can force AutoMapper to throw an exception for unmapped properties. If trusting AutoMapper to realize TestClass.Id and LdbRecords.Id isn't good enough, then the application won't build / run (Unit testing is ideal here too).

Comment: `var` yuk :) Thanks, I will definitely revisit AutoMapper at a later date; previously I decided not to go down that route, but it is possible my reasons are no longer relevant.

Comment: @LeeTickett var yuk? lol. Yes, it would be a decent sized change but well worth it